# How QEMU knows the branch direction of a TB which had been executed?

Tags: qemu

I am trying to understand the block chaining of QEMU.
And I have a question about the branch direction of each executed TBs. 
Suppose the TB#1 has been executed now, and find the next_tb (TB#2). 
Then we know the direction is TB#1--->TB#2 and store the chain in code cache for speedup the
execution next time.
So, *next time qemu find the next TB (which is TB#1), then TB#1--->TB#2 will be executed in code cache.*

But I think that there are two branch direction of a TB.(branch taken/not taken)
My question is how qemu ensure the direction is TB#1--->TB#2 next time?

Thanks all.

Comment: I suggest changing the acronym TB to BT so that it reflects "branch taken". Thus BT1 reflects branch taken 1, BT2 reflects branch taken 2 and so on. Also mention the architecture that you are referring to here. As far as I know, qemu tries to emulate the underlying architecture, plus the cpu specific behavior. Thus it may reflect the way it is actually done for the corresponding architecture and cpu pair.

Comment: Hello, Pegasus.  Sorry about that I didn't show the full name of TB, the TB is equal to "Translation Block" which is a basic block for translating target instructions into host instructions in qemu.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same question

Answer (score 0):

THE TB has two out bound links (though one may be unused for
an unconditional branch). When we chain a TB together we only
chain the link that we took. So if we do a "branch taken" exit
from TB1 and find that it goes to TB2, then we link TB1's
branch-taken code path directly to TB2. But that doesn't affect
the branch-not-taken codepath. Later if we do a branch-not-taken
exit from TB1 we may be able to chain it to a different TB.

(In fact the outbound links are just numbered 0 and 1, and
there's no requirement to use them for taken and not-taken
in any particular order.)